# orthogonal vector field under reparametrization

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

Some context:
Given a parametrized surface $\alpha$ of an open set A$\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ one can define two orthogonal vector fields by
$F_{\pm}(\alpha(p)):=\pm\frac{ \partial_x \alpha(p)\times\partial_y \alpha(p)}{|\partial_x \alpha(p)\times\partial_y \alpha(p)|}$

Now consider a reparametrization $\beta:$ A' $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, does $F_{\pm}(\beta(p'))$ equal $F_{\pm}(\alpha(p))$ (this would mean invariance) or not. If not calculate $F_{\pm}(\beta(p'))$

At the beginning i thought that it should be invariant, but after calculating a example this doesn't seen to hold. Now I don't know how to calculate $F_{\pm}(\beta(p'))$. (I would need a explanation how exactly to calculate it)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: how you define a reparametrization? How two parametrization of the same surface are related?

Comment: @ecrin yeah but I don't see how to use it in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the surface seen as subset or $\mathbb R^3$, $x\in S$.Up to restrain the domain, you can consider $\alpha\colon U\to S$ and $\beta\colon V\to S$ injective maps such that $x\in\alpha(U)\cap\beta(V)$.

As they are riparameterization
$$
\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
U @>{\beta^{-1}\alpha}>> V\\
@V{\alpha}VV @VV{\beta}V \\
S @>{Id}>> S
\end{CD}
$$
$\beta^{-1}\circ\alpha$ is a local diffeomorphism of $\mathbb R^2$.

Then let $\alpha(p)=x$, $p'=\beta^{-1}(\alpha(p))$, $$d_{p}\alpha=d_{p}(\beta\circ\beta^{-1}\circ\alpha)=d_{p'}\beta\cdot d_p(\beta^{-1}\circ\alpha).$$

Now, the tangent space $T_x S$ is $d_p \alpha(\mathbb R^2)$, or $d_{p'}\beta(\mathbb R^2)$: the definition is consistent as we showed that they are equal as $d_p(\beta^{-1}\circ\alpha)$ is a linear isomorphism of $\mathbb R^2$.

Particularly, any two linear indipendent vector of this plane have the same normal vector, up to sign, which answers to your question.